# Statistics of the yearly amount of beds in private prisons in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, crime

I'm seeking a list of how many prisoners got incarnated in each year in the US by private prisons compared to state-run facilities. Is such a list publically available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is tons of data at the US [Bureau of Justice Statistcs - Corrections](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=1)

But I think the best way is to get these data points from the two major private prison companies (CCA and GEO Group).

Luckily (for you), both are publicly traded - so you can download their annual reports and find all sorts of info about number of beds, and different types of housing.

For example, from the GEO Group 2012 annual report ([PDF](https://materials.proxyvote.com/Approved/36159R/20130314/AR_159415/document.pdf))
[image]

So then you just need to download a bunch of PDFs, and then copy/paste into a spreadsheet.

- CCA annual reports (2008 - 2014) - http://www.cca.com/investors/financial-information/annual-reports
- GEO Group annual reports (2001 to 2014) - http://www.snl.com/irweblinkx/FinancialDocs.aspx?iid=4144107

p.s. you can get more years of annual reports by contacting to the investor relations department

Comment: It's sad that the only reason this data is public is because the corporations   running the prisons are owned by shareholders and required to post annual financial reports.